# How to generate a unique id like TeamViewer C#?

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good way to uniquely identify a computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671876/whats-a-good-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-computer)

As the title above, someone know how to generate a unique id like TeamViewer for licensing purpose in C#.

I want to call a function that should return 1 unique ID for a PC every time like TeamViewer. I want to use that like a hardware ID for license management.

Comment: Are you talking about a UUID/GUID? Give us an example of what you're referring to.

Comment: Are you looking for [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)?

Comment: I think GUID is not. I want every time call function that will return 1 unique ID on 1 PC like TeamViewer. I want use that like a hardware ID for license management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) method

```
public static Guid NewGuid();
```

Every time you call this method a new `Guid` is generated.

**Edit: Based on your comments**

[Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the thing you can use. For instance you can use the following code to get BIOS id's of the system.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new 
    ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM 
    Win32_BIOS"); 

foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("BIOS Serial Number: " + 
        wmi.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString()); 
}
```

Similarly you can get other system information and work with it to generate a unique id of a system. [Here is a good article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23095/Obtain-System-Information-Using-Windows-Management) from where you can take help. Please have a look.

Comment: I think GUID is not. I want every time call function that will return 1 unique ID on 1 PC like TeamViewer. I want use that like a hardware ID for license management.

Comment: @Shinichi Just updated my answer, please have a look.