# Get Mac Address Using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, mac-address

I'm trying to put some basic level of protection to an Excel (for Windows) application I'm writing. I was thinking on generating a license file using the machine's mac address. My question is: how can I get the Mac Address using VBScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dim WMI:  set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
dim Nads: set Nads = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter where physicaladapter=true") 
dim nad
for each Nad in Nads
    if not isnull(Nad.MACAddress) then Wscript.Echo Nad.description, Nad.MACAddress   
next
```

However MAC can be a poor choice; [What's a good way to uniquely identify a computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671876/whats-a-good-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-computer).

This will return all physical adapters, but for me I also see my `Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows` which I would not describe as physical.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It worked correctly. Regarding your comment on it being a poor choice, I agree. But we just need a simple and fast method to discourage inproper use of the tool. Since only a few copies of it will be distributed, we think this can be enough (for now).

Comment: @Alex, but how to get only the "active" network's mac address?

Comment: Hope this is not too late @SahilMittal, the active one may be determined by checking other properties on the [Win32_NetworkAdapter from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx), look for **NetConnectionStatus = 2** + **Speed not null and > 0**, if both wired, wifi connected, mobile network connected, you will have to pick one based on  **AdapterType**.