# How to retrieve WMI data such as UUID from a C# program?

Tags: c#, c, wmi, system, wmic

To retrieve system's UUID we have the option of WMIC command-line utility

```
wmic csproduct get uuid
```

How to retrieve the same uuid from a system using C or C# program or using .dll?

Comment: Google for c# wmi query for many examples

Comment: unique UUID using C# in Windows http://stackoverflow.com/a/32636967/2801351

Answer (score 7):

You can get the Universally unique identifier (UUID) value from the [`Win32_ComputerSystemProduct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class, try this sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                ManagementScope Scope;                
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT UUID FROM Win32_ComputerSystemProduct");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","UUID",WmiObject["UUID"]);// String                     
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```