# How to create a beacon with c# and windows 10 annniversary update

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-10-universal

For a prototype I am currently trying to create a bluetooth beacon with c#. I found a few promising examples

- https://gist.github.com/petrosoininen/869059881614f32854a1
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement/cs/Scenario2_Publisher.xaml.cs
- [setting the BluetoothLEAdvertisement.Flags in C# for iBeacon advertisemet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756441/setting-the-bluetoothleadvertisement-flags-in-c-sharp-for-ibeacon-advertisemet)

for UWP. Problem is ... none of these seem to work.

When calling `_bluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher.Start();`on either of the examples im am getting a exception with the message saying "Die Daten sind unzulässig. Es wurde eine ungültige Anzeigennutzlast erkannt." wich means "Invalid data. Invalid (display?) paylad detected".

First question that comes to my mind is if I should set `ManufacturerData` or `DataSections` on `_bluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher.Advertisement`? Or Both?
Second question: Did windows anniversary update may killed the above examples?

Answer (score 0):

Found a working example. So calling this resolved.

http://tomipaananen.azurewebsites.net/?p=111

Comment: This link is offline unfortunately. Do you still have a working example for beacons on Windows 10? Thx!