# What is Win32_OperatingSystem SerialNumber and is it considered sensitive information?

Tags: windows, operating-system

I'm trying to find a way to uniquely identify PCs and thought the .SerialNumber from Win32_OperatingSystem would meet my needs. But I don't want to upset anyone by collecting something that might be considered sensitive information.

So what is Win32_OperatingSystem.SerialNumber used for, but more importantly is it considered sensitive; as far as I can tell it's not a product key or anything like that?

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:")
Set props = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each prop In props
        systemSpecs = prop.Caption
    Next prop
```

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671876/whats-a-good-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer here: [difference between product key and serial number](https://superuser.com/questions/618552/difference-between-product-key-and-serial-number)

In a nutshell (which is all I need):

- **Serial Number** is *like* a Name
- **Product Key** is *like* a Password