# What parameter to use as a unique computer ID to secure my app

Tags: python, mac-address, unique-id, motherboard

I am looking for a personal Computer ID that I can use to secure my app so that only one Computer can use it.

I can't use the MAC address because a user can have multiple Network adapters so I was thinking about a Motherboard ID if it exists!

I am using python so I hope these IDs can be read with it!

```
***# - registering & checking MAC Address :
registered_mac_address = '88:b1:11:e9:5e:53'

print('checking MAC Address ...')
this_mac_address = get_mac_address()
print(f'mac: {this_mac_address}')

if registered_mac_address != this_mac_address:
    print('this app is not registered for this Computer!')
    ui.lbl_mac_address.setText('NOT REGISTERED!')
    msg_box('Not Registered', 'This Computer is not Registered for this application!')
    sys.exit()
else:
    ui.lbl_mac_address.setText(registered_mac_address)***
```

Comment: Best way is to use some sort of 2FA mechanism

Comment: Or just don't do that. Corporate customers will generally properly license your app, and making end users pay multiple times for multiple installations e.g. within the family is just shitty.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to prevent piracy of your app, what you are looking for is a [software license key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599837/how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key). You create them and distribute/sell them to allow users to run your code. But efficient anty-piracy measures are difficult to implement.

If what you want is to ensure that the code is run by a specific computer, you can try to identify the computer using methods listed in this [other StackOverflow question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671876/whats-a-good-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-computer).

In any case, Python is a powerfull language, you will be able to do what you want with it, either way you go.